# How do I pipe grep commands with a "-" without it being interpreted as an option?

Tags: command-line, grep, debian

I'm using a Kali Linux distribution and I'm trying to learn how to use the | character for piping using grep. If I wanted to search the hashcat help file for what -a means for example, how would I do so without -a being considered an option to grep? I successfully used hashcat --help | grep 3000 to find out what hash mode 3000 means. But if I wanted to quickly search the help for -a how would I do so? I'm under the impression it might have something to do with regular expressions vs extended expressions but I don't really understand them.

Comment: Tip: Your question is relevant for Ubuntu, but by mentioning Kali, people will vote to close your question, because AskUbuntu is strictly about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to use `--` to stop looking for options. See the following examples

```
man df|grep --color -- '-'
```

and

```
man df|grep --color -- '-a'
```